# How do I stop ts-node-dev from sending a desktop notification upon restart?

Tags: node.js, ts-node

`ts-node-dev` is spewing a desktop notification every time it restarts.  This is super-annoying. How do I turn them off?

Comment: do you mean ts-node-dev ?

Answer (score 9):

Create/edit a file named `.node-dev.json` in project root with the following contents:

```
{
  "notify": false
}
```

Or directly use the command line option:

```
--no-notify
```

Source: https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev